# C++, OpenCv, Android NDK, Failure to Rotate Mat in Place

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am trying to use OpenCv's roate() function to rotate a 3:4 Mat in place. My function call is as follows....

```
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_company_example_camera_CaptureActivity_getResultMat
        (JNIEnv *env,
         jobject instance,
         jlong mat, jint width,
         jint height)
{
    Mat& inputMat = *(Mat*) mat;
    cv::rotate(inputMat, inputMat, 0);

    //attemping to resize after rotate gives me a similar error...
    //Mat outputMat(inputMat.rows, inputMat.cols, inputMat.type());
    //cv::resize(inputMat, outputMat, outputMat.size());
    //inputMat = outputMat;
}
```

I call this function from the following overridden OpenCv function...

```
@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    Mat mat = inputFrame.rgba();
    getResultMat(mat.getNativeObjAddr(), 500, 500); 
    return mat;
}
```

The resulting camera frame is completely black. When I look in the log, I see the following error...

```
com.company.example.camera E/cv::error(): OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (src.dims == 2 && info.height == (uint32_t)src.rows && info.width == (uint32_t)src.cols) in void Java_org_opencv_android_Utils_nMatToBitmap2(JNIEnv*, jclass, jlong, jobject, jboolean), file /build/master_pack-android/opencv/modules/java/generator/src/cpp/utils.cpp, line 97
11-29 02:14:08.501 26116-26571/com.company.example.camera E/org.opencv.android.Utils: nMatToBitmap catched cv::Exception: /build/master_pack-android/opencv/modules/java/generator/src/cpp/utils.cpp:97: error: (-215) src.dims == 2 && info.height == (uint32_t)src.rows && info.width == (uint32_t)src.cols in function void Java_org_opencv_android_Utils_nMatToBitmap2(JNIEnv*, jclass, jlong, jobject, jboolean)
11-29 02:14:08.501 26116-26571/com.company.example.camera E/CameraBridge: Mat type: Mat [ 960*720*CV_8UC4, isCont=true, isSubmat=false, nativeObj=0x7f7f659fc0, dataAddr=0x7f5aa80000 ]
11-29 02:14:08.501 26116-26571/com.company.example.camera E/CameraBridge: Bitmap type: 960*720
11-29 02:14:08.501 26116-26571/com.company.example.camera E/CameraBridge: Utils.matToBitmap() throws an exception: /build/master_pack-android/opencv/modules/java/generator/src/cpp/utils.cpp:97: error: (-215) src.dims == 2 && info.height == (uint32_t)src.rows && info.width == (uint32_t)src.cols in function void Java_org_opencv_android_Utils_nMatToBitmap2(JNIEnv*, jclass, jlong, jobject, jboolean)
```

and for resize...

```
E/cv::error(): OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (src.dims == 2 && info.height == (uint32_t)src.rows && info.width == (uint32_t)src.cols) in void Java_org_opencv_android_Utils_nMatToBitmap2(JNIEnv*, jclass, jlong, jobject, jboolean), file /build/master_pack-android/opencv/modules/java/generator/src/cpp/utils.cpp, line 97
11-29 15:39:47.801 8916-9365/com.company.example.camera E/org.opencv.android.Utils: nMatToBitmap catched cv::Exception: /build/master_pack-android/opencv/modules/java/generator/src/cpp/utils.cpp:97: error: (-215) src.dims == 2 && info.height == (uint32_t)src.rows && info.width == (uint32_t)src.cols in function void Java_org_opencv_android_Utils_nMatToBitmap2(JNIEnv*, jclass, jlong, jobject, jboolean)
11-29 15:39:47.801 8916-9365/com.company.example.camera E/CameraBridge: Mat type: Mat [ 500*500*CV_8UC4, isCont=true, isSubmat=false, nativeObj=0x7f6d591140, dataAddr=0x7f5cfc0000 ]
11-29 15:39:47.801 8916-9365/com.company.example.camera E/CameraBridge: Bitmap type: 960*720
11-29 15:39:47.801 8916-9365/com.company.example.camera E/CameraBridge: Utils.matToBitmap() throws an exception: /build/master_pack-android/opencv/modules/java/generator/src/cpp/utils.cpp:97: error: (-215) src.dims == 2 && info.height == (uint32_t)src.rows && info.width == (uint32_t)src.cols in function void Java_org_opencv_android_Utils_nMatToBitmap2(JNIEnv*, jclass, jlong, jobject, jboolean)
```

To me, this suggests that there is some sort of logic error, but I'm pretty sure that I have used the rotate and resize functions properly. Further, I know the input mat is being correctly passed to the native function - when I do direct pixel manipulation everything works as I expect it to.